# python list sending odd results

Tags: python, arrays, object, terminal

for learning, i had to create a class User, use that class to create objects and finally add them to another list via a for loop. but the result sent are unexpected and totally different from waht i wanted. here's the class:

```
class User:
def __init__(self, firstname : str='', lastname: str = '', email: str='', newsletter : boolean = False):
    self.firstname = firstname,
    self.lastname = lastname,
    self.email = email,
    self.newsletter = newsletter
```

and here are the objects:

```
new_users = [
User('Joe', 'Dalton', 'joe.dalton@example.com', True),
User('William', 'Dalton', 'william.dalton@example.com'),
User('Jack', 'Dalton', 'jack.dalton@example.com'),
User('Averell', 'Dalton', 'averell.dalton@example.com', True)
```

]

the loop is right here:

```
users = []
for i in range (len(new_users)):
    users.append(str(new_users))
    print(users)
```

here's what i have in the terminal:

```
['[<__main__.User object at 0x7f4c363da1f0>, <__main__.User object at    0x7f4c363c2f10>, <__main__.User object at 0x7f4c3639b9a0>, <__main__.User object at 0x7f4c36326250>]', '[<__main__.User object at 0x7f4c363da1f0>, <__main__.User object at 0x7f4c363c2f10>, <__main__.User object at 0x7f4c3639b9a0>, <__main__.User object at 0x7f4c36326250>]', '[<__main__.User object at 0x7f4c363da1f0>, <__main__.User object at 0x7f4c363c2f10>, <__main__.User object at 0x7f4c3639b9a0>, <__main__.User object at 0x7f4c36326250>]', '[<__main__.User object at 0x7f4c363da1f0>, <__main__.User object at 0x7f4c363c2f10>, <__main__.User object at 0x7f4c3639b9a0>, <__main__.User object at 0x7f4c36326250>]']
```

Comment: Your objects are not printable, you should look at the function __ str __ to make it printable

Comment: What's the point of trying to duplicate an existing list? Are you sure this is what is being requested? Is not rather to generate a list of User objects **from a list of the parameters**?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print an object in a format that's understandable/meaningful to the reader then you should implement the __str__() function.

Also, it looks like you're misunderstanding how you would iterate over your list to print the values.

Perhaps this will make things clearer:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, firstname='', lastname='', email='', newsletter=False):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.email = email
        self.newsletter = newsletter
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.firstname=}, {self.lastname=}, {self.email=}, {self.newsletter=}'.replace('self.', '')

new_users = [
    User('Joe', 'Dalton', 'joe.dalton@example.com', True),
    User('William', 'Dalton', 'william.dalton@example.com'),
    User('Jack', 'Dalton', 'jack.dalton@example.com'),
    User('Averell', 'Dalton', 'averell.dalton@example.com', True)]

for user in new_users:
    print(user)
```

**Output:**

```
firstname='Joe', lastname='Dalton', email='joe.dalton@example.com', newsletter=True
firstname='William', lastname='Dalton', email='william.dalton@example.com', newsletter=False
firstname='Jack', lastname='Dalton', email='jack.dalton@example.com', newsletter=False
firstname='Averell', lastname='Dalton', email='averell.dalton@example.com', newsletter=True
```

Comment: the thing is that i want to add the users instanciated it in another list (it's an exercise in formation)

Answer (score 2):

While iterating objects you are adding it wrong. Also remove the comma in the constructor variable assignments. **str** method makes the printing readable It should be like below:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, firstname : str='', lastname: str = '', email: str='', newsletter:bool = False):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.email = email
        self.newsletter = newsletter
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.firstname} {self.lastname}"
        
new_users = [
User('Joe', 'Dalton', 'joe.dalton@example.com', True),
User('William', 'Dalton', 'william.dalton@example.com'),
User('Jack', 'Dalton', 'jack.dalton@example.com'),
User('Averell', 'Dalton', 'averell.dalton@example.com', True)]

users = []
for new_user in new_users:
    users.append(new_user)
    
for user in users:
    print(user)
```

Comment: can you show me the output please?